# Azure Cosmos Gremlin out() odd behaviour

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am experimenting with gremlin using our user access data and getting some very odd results when traversing `out()` of a vertex.

So to set the scene:

- There are about 130K users and about 130K accounts.
- Each account/user has a *serviceId* and i have used this id as the partition key.
- The edges between accounts and users show the access (read/write etc) and no edge implies no access at all.

I am experimenting with a user that has access to about 23K accounts.

Running:

- `g.V('62266').out()` returns 15 unique vertexes (should be ~23K). The accounts are also from various partitions.
- `g.V('62266').outE()` returns 10000 unique edges (i imagine that is the limit from cosmos).
- `g.V("62266").union(identity(), g.V().hasLabel("Account").has("ServiceId", "AU1461"))` run in the vscode cosmos plugin returns a very pretty graph showing edges from the user to all the accounts (about 70), indicating that it rightfully knows the edges exist between these vertices (even though they are not returned by the first query).

I have been scouring the cosmos docs and have yet to find anything about limits on `out()` or anything similar (or even a reproduction of the problem)

Can someone help explain the discrepancy between the amount of edges on the '62266' vertex and the amount of vertexes returned when traversing out from '62266'?